# Apache CXF FaultListener not registered in cxf bus

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jax-ws, cxf

I have a Spring application that uses Apache CXF. I need do some additional stuff when an error occurs. To do this, I created a custom implementation of the FaultListener interface:

```
public class MyClass implements FaultListener {
    @Override
    public boolean faultOccurred(Exception exception, String description, Message message) {
        // do stuff

        return true;
    }
}
```

I registered the listener in the CXF bus, but CXF is unable to find my listener.

```
<bean id="gzipInInterceptor" class="org.apache.cxf.transport.common.gzip.GZIPInInterceptor" />    
<bean id="listener" class="MyClass"/>
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="org.apache.cxf.logging.FaultListener">
            <ref bean="listener"/>
        </entry>
    </cxf:properties>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="gzipInInterceptor" />            
    </cxf:inInterceptors>       
    <cxf:inFaultInterceptors>
        <ref bean="gzipInInterceptor" />
    </cxf:inFaultInterceptors>   
</cxf:bus>
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3):

have a look on this

`<bean id="listener" class="MyClass"/>`

You need to provide full class path including package name or no need of declaring bean here rather use

```
        <entry key="org.apache.cxf.logging.FaultListener">
            <bean class="your.package.name.MyClass" />
        </entry>
```